# Access all variables within a function even when error is thrown?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Below I have a `main` function. This function has many other variables declared in it and runs many functions. If an error occurs within the function I can catch this error but within my catch I do not have the value for the `main` function. I'm looking for a way to have access to all the variables even when an error is thrown.

```
export async function main ({alpha, beta, gamma}) {
  let one = await doSomething(alpha)
  let two = await doSomethingElse(one, beta)
  return {one, two}
}

export async function store (db) {
  await db.insert(data)
}

export async function usage (db, data) {
  try {
    let operation = await main(data)
    await store (db, operation)
    return operation
  } catch (e) {
    // here we don't have access to operation variables :(
    await store(db, {}, e.message)
    throw e
  }
}
```

The only reasonable way i've found to do this is to create a class where each value in the `main` function.

```
import { get } from 'lodash'

export class Operation () {
  constructor(db){
    this.db = db
  }
  main({alpha, beta, gamma}) {
    this.one = await doSomething(alpha)
    this.two = await doSomethingElse(one, beta)
    return {one: this.one, two: this.two}    
  }
  init(data) {
    try {
      let main = await this.main(data)
      await this.store(main)
      return main
    } catch (e) {
      await this.store()
      throw e
    }
  }
  store(data = {}, errorMessage) {
    if (!data.one) data.one = get(this, 'one') || null
    if (!data.two) data.two = get(this, 'two') || null
    if (errorMessage) data.errMessage = errorMessage
    return await this.db.insert(data)
  }
}
```

How can I have access to all the variables within a function even when an error is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use `var` to declare a function-scoped variable instead of one that is scoped to the `let` block.

However, you really should just use two `try`/`catch` statements, for you are trying to catch two different errors and going to handle them differently:

```
try {
    let operation = await main(data)
    try {
        await store (db, operation)
    } catch(e) {
        // here we do have access to the `operation` variable :)
    }
    return operation
} catch (e) { // failed to create operation (or the inner catch did rethrow)
    await store(db, {}, e.message)
    throw e
}
```

Comment: You might still want the first `await` inside the `try`, in case it fails - just declare the `operation` var in the outer scope.

Comment: @nrabinowitz: No, I really meant to put the first `await` outside of the inner `try`, so that exceptions/rejections are caught by the outer `catch` block. Of course, there are many ways to skin a cat, this might or might not be what one actually needs.

Comment: @Bergi The idea is that I would want to access the value from `one` even if `doSomethingElse` throws an error.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: For that, you should catch the rejection of `doSomethingElse` inside `main` and pass the respective values back (e.g. `null` instead of `two`)

Answer (score 0):

I created this class and wrapper function `alwaysRunner`. which takes two function arguments and will always provide the available variables to the secondary function.

```
export class AlwaysRunner {
  constructor(operation, reguardless, optional = {}){
    Object.assign(this, optional)
    this.operation = operation.bind(this)
    this.reguardless = reguardless.bind(this)
  }
  async init(data) {
    let operation = this.operation
    let reguardless = this.reguardless
    let optional = this.optional
    delete this.operation
    delete this.reguardless
    delete this.optional
    try {
      let main = await operation(data)
      await reguardless(this)
      return main
    } catch (error) {
      await reguardless({...this, error})
      throw error
    }
  }
}

export async function alwaysRunner(operation, reguardless, optional) {
  return await new AlwaysRunner(operation, reguardless, optional).init()
}
```

Here's some tests on how it works.

```
describe('alwaysRunner', () => {

  it('should work', async () => {
    let ran = [false, false]
    await alwaysRunner(function () {
      ran[0] = true
      this.alpha = true
      this.beta = true
      return this
    }, function (values) {
      ran[1] = true
      assert.equal(values.alpha, true)
      assert.equal(values.beta, true)
      assert.equal(values.error, undefined)
    }).should.not.be.rejected
    assert.deepEqual(ran, [true, true])
  })

  it('should work with thrown error', async () => {
    let ran = [false, false]
    await alwaysRunner(function () {
      ran[0] = true
      this.alpha = true
      throw new Error('some error')
      this.beta = true
    }, function (values) {
      ran[1] = true
      assert.equal(values.alpha, true)
      assert.equal(values.beta, undefined)
      assert.equal(values.error, new Error('some error'))
    }).should.be.rejected
    assert.deepEqual(ran, [true, true])
  })

})
```